# how to know what computers are connected to an AP?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dhcp

The access point doesn't have DHCP enabled, so I can't look the DHCP table.

Is there a way to ping an IP and know what AP is using?

Edit:

I know what IPs are on the network using `nmap`, but when I Traceroute to those IPs I only see the AP I'm connected to, an the IP I'm tracing to. Nothing in between.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can run a Traceroute to every possible IP address in your network. Based on the response you can determine who is connected to what. However, this is usually unreasonable - on a basic home network there can be within 255 - 65,536 possible IP addresses to check.

EDIT: (Face palm - For some reason I though we were talking about a wired network)
Using a sniffing program like Kismet (http://www.kismetwireless.net/) will allow you to find the Mac addresses of all the clients. Then with the arp-scan tool (http://linux.die.net/man/1/arp-scan) you can then turn those Mac adress into IP adresses. (Linux only)

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to log into the AP's web interface and find a list of associated MAC addresses.

If it doesn't tell you the IP of them, you can try [arping](http://freecode.com/projects/arping) which should tell you the IP.

It may be possible to sniff the channel the AP is on if your WLAN card supports monitor mode - you might be able to enumerate any MAC you see on the network at the very least.  I know there's tools for Linux that might accomplish this, don't know about Windows.  I don't have any experience doing this but may be something to look into.

Your AP may have "AP Isolation" enabled which prevents you from contacting any other STA on that WLAN.

Comment: The AP is an old Linksys and the web admin doesn't say anything. I'll try `arping`and see what happens.

Comment: `arping` won't do anything if A) you don't have a MAC and B) AP Isolation is enabled.